# Unresolved external errors while using TList in C++

Tags: clang, linker-errors, c++builder, 32-bit

I have the following linker errors when compiling a project using bcc32c (Embarcadero):

It looks like he is not finding the library **VCL**.

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrAsg(System::AnsiStringT&, System::AnsiStringT) 
 referenced from ...DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_t_win32

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrCat(System::AnsiStringT&, System::AnsiStringT) 

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrCat3(System::AnsiStringT&, System::AnsiStringT)

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrClr(void *) referenced from ...

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrCmp()

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrDelete(System::AnsiStringT&, int, int) referenced 
from ...

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrFromArray(System::AnsiStringT&, char *, int, 
unsigned short) referenced from 

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall LStrFromPChar(System::AnsiStringT&, char *, unsigned 
short) referenced from...

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external System::__linkproc__ 
__fastcall StrFromUStr(System::AnsiStringT&,System::UnicodeString, 
unsigned short) referenced from...
```

Comment: When you created the project, did you enable VCL support up front?  What kind of project are you creating?  A GUI app or a console app?

Comment: I created a project that should be a VCL-dependent project (option when creating)
for some reason, I guess I should not have checked this option when creating.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the linker can not resolve the VCL class references.

Insert in your project a VCL C++ Form.

Right click on the project and Add New->VCL Form C++ Builder

It is not necessary to save the unit.h/.cpp.
You can in sequence delete the form from your project. This is only necessary for the link to be created

[image: right click on the project]

Embarcadero put in your .cbproj the code FrameworkType = VCL.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{xxxx}/ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectVersion>XX.Y</ProjectVersion>
    <FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>
```

The problem must be solved.